# Remove unwanted region in image by matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, classification, image-segmentation

I have a image that includes object and some unwanted region (small dots). I want to remove it. Hence, I use some morphological operator example 'close' to remove. But it is not perfect. Do you have other way to remove more clear? You can download example image at [raw image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz4s8lsnu0kg43k/Image.mat)

This is my code

```
load Image.mat %load Img value
Img= bwmorph(Img,'close');
imshow(Img);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The `raw image` link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might prefer a faster and vectorized approach using `bsxfun` along with the information  obtained from `bwlabel` itself.

**Note:** `bsxfun` is memory intensive, but that's precisely what makes it faster. Therefore, watch out for the size of `B1` in the code below. This method will get slower once it reaches the memory constraints set by the system, but until then it provides good speedup over the `regionprops` method.

**Code**

```
[L,num] = bwlabel( Img );
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
B1 = bsxfun(@eq,L,permute(find(counts>threshold),[1 3 2]));
NewImg = sum(B1,3)>0;
```

**EDIT 1:** Few benchmarks for comparisons between `bsxfun` and `regionprops` approaches are discussed next.

**Case 1**

**Benchmark Code**

```
Img = imread('coins.png');%%// This one is chosen as it is available in MATLAB image library
Img = im2bw(Img,0.4); %%// 0.4 seemed good to make enough blobs for this image

lb = bwlabel( Img );
threshold = 2000;

disp('--- With regionprops method:');
tic,out1 = regionprops_method1(Img,lb,threshold);toc
clear out1

disp('---- With bsxfun method:');
tic,out2 = bsxfun_method1(Img,lb,threshold);toc

%%// For demo, that we have rejected enough unwanted blobs
figure,
subplot(211),imshow(Img);
subplot(212),imshow(out2);
```

**Output**

[image]

**Benchmark Results**

```
--- With regionprops method:
Elapsed time is 0.108301 seconds.
---- With bsxfun method:
Elapsed time is 0.006021 seconds.
```

**Case 2**

**Benchmark Code (Only the changes from Case 1 are listed)**

```
Img = imread('snowflakes.png');%%// This one is chosen as it is available in MATLAB image library
Img = im2bw(Img,0.2); %%// 0.2 seemed good to make enough blobs for this image
threshold = 20;
```

**Output**

[image]

**Benchmark Results**

```
--- With regionprops method:
Elapsed time is 0.116706 seconds.
---- With bsxfun method:
Elapsed time is 0.012406 seconds.
```

As pointed out earlier, I have tested with other bigger images and with a lot of unwanted blobs, for which `bsxfun` method doesn't provide any improvement over `regionprops` method. Due to the unavailability of any such bigger images in MATLAB library, they couldn't be discussed here. To sum up, it could be suggested to use either of these two approaches based on the input features. It would be interesting to see how these two approaches perform for your input images.

Comment: can you provide a `tic` `toc` runtime comparison with `regionprops`. How much faster is `bsxfun`?

Comment: @Shai Check out Edit -1.

Comment: +1 for the extensive benchmarking! very nice and high quality answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `regionprops` and `bwlabel` to select all regions that are smaller than a certain area (=number of pixels)

```
lb = bwlabel( Img );
st = regionprops( lb, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList' );
toRemove = [st.Area] < threshold; % fix your threshold here
newImg = Img;
newImg( vertcat( st(toRemove).PixelIdxList ) ) = 0; % remove
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But your code has some error. I buit it and received error:"Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in removeUnwantedRegion (line 6)
newImg( [st(toRemove).PixelIdxList] ) = 0; % remove " .  My image size is 384x384

Comment: The error occured at newImg( [st(toRemove).PixelIdxList] ) = 0; . I debug it I found it

Comment: @user3336190 my bad: Matlab stores `PixelIdxList` as column vectors for each region. When joining all of them together one need to CAT them vertically (using `vertcat`) and not horizontally (using `[]`).