# Display second longest line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

When using a binary image with several lines I know that this code displays the longest line:

```
lineStats = regionprops(imsk, {'Area','PixelIdxList'});
[length, index] = max([lineStats.Area]);
longestLine = zeros(size(imsk));
longestLine(lineStats(index).PixelIdxList)=1;
figure
imshow(longestLine)
```

Is there a way to display the second longest line? I need to display a line that is a little shorter than the longest line in order to connect them.

EDIT: Is there a way to display both lines on the binary image figure?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding your edit.  Yes, simply use `index` and `index2` from Trogdor's code and repeating the `longestLine(...) = 1;` calculation twice - once for each variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `max` use `sort` in descending order and take the second element. Like `max`, `sort` also provides the indexes of the returned values, so the two functions are pretty compatible.

```
eStats = regionprops(imsk, {'Area','PixelIdxList'});
[length, index] = sort([lineStats.Area], 'descend');
longestLine = zeros(size(imsk));
longestLine(lineStats(index(2)).PixelIdxList)=1; % here take the second largest
figure
imshow(longestLine)
```

Comment: Instead of `index(2)` you can use `index([2,3])` to display the 2nd and 3rd longest lines. Just provide a vector with the lines that you want to display.

Answer (score 5):

I would set the longest line to zero and use max again, after I copy the original vector.

```
lineStats = regionprops(imsk, {'Area','PixelIdxList'});
[length, index] = max([lineStats.Area]);
lineAreas = [lineStats.Area]; %copy all lineStats.Area values into a new vector
lineAreas(index) = NaN; %remove the longest line by setting it to not-a-number
[length2, index2] = max(lineAreas);
```

**EDIT: Response to new question**

`sort` may be a more straight forward approach for multiples, but you can still use max.

```
lineAreas = [lineStats.Area]; %copy all lineStats.Area values into a new vector
% add a for loop that iteratively stores the desired indices
nLines = 3; 
index = zeros(1,nLines);
for iLines = 1:nLines
    [length, index(iLines)] = max(lineAreas);
    lineAreas(index) = NaN; %remove the longest line by setting it to not-a-number
end
longestLine = zeros(size(imsk));
% I cannot be certain this will work since your example is not reproducible
longestLine([lineStats(index).PixelIdxList]) = 1;
figure
imshow(longestLine)
```

Comment: More efficient than sorting. You have my vote. +1.

Comment: But less general, what if you want the 5th longest line? Or if you want the 2nd, 4th and 6th shortest lines?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The question is not generalized. The OP specifically wants the second longest line.  If the question was asking for the n'th longest line, that's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative with focus on performance and ease of use, here's one approach using [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) instead of `regionprops` -

```
[L, num] = bwlabel(imsk, 8);
count_pixels_per_obj = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
[~,sidx] = sort(count_pixels_per_obj,'descend');

N = 3; % Shows N biggest objects/lines
figure,imshow(ismember(L,sidx(1:N))),title([num2str(N) ' biggest blobs'])
```

On the performance aspect, [`here's one post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630775/3293881) that does some benchmarking on `snowflakes` and `coins` images from MATLAB's image gallery.

Sample run -

```
imsk = im2bw(imread('coins.png')); %%// Coins photo from MATLAB Library
```

N = 2:

[image]

N = 3:

[image]